# Why Global Store in Kafka Streams don't use updater processor to restore at the start time?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm going to use a Global Store in my stream processing:

```
         addGlobalStore(
            Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder<String, FiscalInfo>(
                Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(storeNames.storeName),
                Serdes.String(),
                objectMapper.jsonSerde()
            ).withLoggingDisabled(),
            storeNames.sourceName,
            StringDeserializer(),
            objectMapper.jsonDeserializer<FiscalInfo>(),
            topicSource,
            storeNames.processorName,
            ProcessorSupplier{ MyProcessor() } )
```

I implemented MyProcessor to update the store.
But I noticed that the processor isn't used during restoring the store at the start time.
I found that code in implementation InMemoryKevValueStore:

```
    @Override
    public void init(final ProcessorContext context,
                     final StateStore root) {
        if (root != null) {
            // register the store
            context.register(root, (key, value) -> put(Bytes.wrap(key), value));
        }

        open = true;
    }
```

This code demonstrates that to restore state uses lambda: `(key, value) -> put(Bytes.wrap(key), value)`. And there is almost the same logic in other implementations of Store.
Why is implemented in such way?
I expected to have option to use connected to the store updater processor for restoring.